# Get verbose name of foreign key from objects _meta dynamically in Django

Tags: django, django-models, meta

For simplicity sake, with models like the following:

```
 class Plan(models.Model)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Phone Plan Name")
     monthly_charge = models.FloatField()
 class Company(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Company Full Name")
     phone_plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan)
 class Client(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Client Full Name")
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Given a string, I want to know if there is an easy way to retrieve the verbose name of a model attribute even if that string traverses through foreign keys.

I know that I can get the verbose name of a `Client` attribute by

```
Client._meta.get_field("name").verbose_name
```

and this would result in "Client Full Name".

But what if I had the string "company__phone_plan__name", I cannot simply use

```
Client._meta.get_field("company__phone_plan__name").verbose_name
```

to arrive at "Phone Plan Name" as it yields an error.

These strings will be dynamic, so I am wondering what is the easiest way to arrive at the proper verbose name of an attribute, even if it traverses models?

This particular case is using Django 1.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not so good answer but if you need what you want you can use this function:

```
def get_verbose_name(model, string):
    fields = string.split('__')

    for field_name in fields[:-1]:
        field = model._meta.get_field(field_name)

        if field.many_to_one:
            model = field.foreign_related_fields[0].model
        elif field.many_to_many or field.one_to_one or field.one_to_many:
            model = field.related_model
        else:
            raise ValueError('incorrect string')

    return model._meta.get_field(fields[-1]).verbose_name
```

This function gets model name and string and return verbose name

You can use it like so:

```
get_verbose_name(Client, 'company__phone_plan__name')
```

Comment: This seems a lot more practical than my suggestion; and this works nicely (I tested in `Django 1.11`)

Comment: This answer will work! Thank you. I was hoping that there would be a one liner built in to Django to deal with this, but this will definitely suffice.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with instances of the models, then you could try this:

```
c = Client.objects.first()

# c._meta.get_field('company').verbose_name
# c.company._meta.get_field('phone_plan').verbose_name
c.company.phone_plan._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name
```

If you are working with classes only, then its a but more complex:

```
field_company = Client._meta.get_field('company')
field_phone_plan = field_company.rel.to._meta.get_field('phone_plan')
field_name = field_phone_plan.rel.to._meta.get_field('name')
field_name.verbose_name

# or one long line
s = Client._meta.get_field('company') \
    .rel.to._meta.get_field('phone_plan') \
    .rel.to._meta.get_field('name') \
    .verbose_name
```

EDIT: 
User @AndreyBerenda points out that the second option does not work for him in `Django 2.1`; I tested only in `1.11`, which was specified in the question.

Comment: you want to do several query to db just for getting verbose name, it is not so good. second choice does not work (django 2.1)(AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'rel')

Comment: @AndreyBerenda yes, the first option does a lot of database hits. The second option works for me in `django 1.11`, and that version is specified in the question.